# Simplify $\left[ 2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) \right]^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

In relation to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3295544/132192), consider the quantity

$$\left[ 2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) \right]^n$$

when $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 2$.
Under these conditions, it should be a real number.

Is it possible to exploit the presence of $n$ both in the denominator and in the power, to further simplify the expression?

---

My attempt:

$$\left[ 2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) \right]^n = \left( e^{i \frac{\pi}{2n}} + e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2n}} \right)^n = \left( i^{\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{1}{i^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right)^n = \left( \frac{i^{\frac{2}{n}} + 1}{i^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right)^n$$

But I am stuck here and I am no more sure that this is a real quantity.

---

**Edit**: trying to evaluate $2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right)$ for some values of $n$, I obtain

$$n = 2; \ 2 \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \sqrt{2}\\
n = 3; \ 2 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \sqrt{3}\\
n = 4; \ 2 \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}{2} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}\\
n = 5; \ 2 \frac{\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5}}}{2 \sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2}}\\
n = 6; \ 2 \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}{2} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}$$

I'm not sure about it being a regular succession. The $n = 5$ term is confusing.

As regards the binomial theorem applied to $\left( e^{i \frac{\pi}{2n}} + e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2n}} \right)^n$, I don't think to be able to manage those terms in the attempt to identify something useful.

Comment: Ignore the power of n outside the brackets, and try different powers of n inside the brackets. You might recognise the results for n = 2 and n = 3... do you see a pattern emerge?

Comment: Using $\cos(x/2)=\sqrt{1+\cos x\over2}$, we get $(1+\cos(\pi/n))^{n/2}$.

Comment: I refer only to the first equation in your attempt; why not expand RHS into a series using the binomial theorem, and see if things get better?

Comment: $\left[ 2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) \right]^n$ is quite simple – what kind of simpler expression do you expect?

Comment: @battletwink69 Tried!

Comment: @Allawonder I edited the question, I am not able to handle the binomial expansion.

Comment: @MartinR As I said in the question, the presence of $n$ both at the denominator and the power may encourage a further work to try if something even simpler can be obtained. It is a possibility, of course, and not a certainty.

Comment: Oops, left something out in my comment above, should be $2^{n/2}(1+\cos(\pi/n))^{n/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Don't see a reason to write in terms of imaginary numbers.
Distribute the power of $n$:
$$\left[ 2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) \right]^n$$
$$= 2^n \left[\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) \right]^n$$

Using the half-angle identity Gerry mentioned:
$$\cos(\frac{x}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}$$
Where $x=\pi/n$:
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n})=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos {\frac{\pi}{n}}}{2}}$$
Subbing back in:
$$= 2^n \left[\frac{1+\cos {\frac{\pi}{n}}}{2} \right]^{n/2}$$
Since $1+\cos {\theta}$ is always positive, this expression will result in a real number.

Comment: How is the result simpler than the primitive?

Comment: You don't have to rewrite $\left[ 2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) \right]^n$ in order to see that it is a real number.